# jquery validation errorPlacement not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im just trying to customize where I put the error messages generated by jQuery validation.  I have the following code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
           a: {required:true, minlength:2}
        },      
        messages: {
           a: {required: "enter your name!"}       
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         if(element.attr('name' == 'a')){
             error.appendTo($('#restErrorDate'));                    
         }
        },
        debug:true
    });
    $('#a').blur(function(){
        $("form").validate().element("#a");
    });
});
```

here is the html:

```
<div>
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
</form>
</div>
<div id="restErrorDate" class="restErrorDate" style="border:1px solid blue;"></div>
```

For some reason it is not working.  Thanks so much in advance for your help...this little thing has been keeping me working for a long time.  Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmw562/S7AKK/38/

Answer (score 5):

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
           a: {required:true, minlength:2}
        },      
        messages: {
           a: {required: "enter your name!"}       
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         if(element.attr('name') == 'a'){
            //               ^--------------missing brackets              
             error.appendTo($('#restErrorDate'));                    
         }
        },
        debug:true
    });
    $('#a').blur(function(){
        $("form").validate().element("#a");
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc6H8/)

Comment: Good! And even better if you put `div#restErrorDate` inside the form element, e.g. right before the form end tag. That way the error message disappears when the input element gets valid.